# Spreadsheet: compare a cells value to a certain range depending on another Value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, comparison, range

Sorry if this has been posted before, my googling skills have not helped me as of yet.

I have a spreadsheet with a long list of all of our items in our store with their category#, cost, and retail. Now I have a little formula set up to show the `GPM%`.

Looks like this in a row

```
|CATEGORY # 1|UPC 12345678912| ITEM NAME | COST 0.59 | RETAIL 1.19 | GPM% 50.42%|
```

in another sheet I have all of the pre-defined ranges our company wants each category to be at. 
Looks like this:

```
|CAT#1 | FROM 35% | TO 40%|
```

How do I make my sheet find an item in whatever category, say `CAT# 1`, compare the current `GP%`, to the range I have for `CAT #1`, then display, somehow, the ones not in range?

Comment: Do you have any experience with VBA?

Comment: I do not, I'm pretty new to spreadsheets in general, but I am able and willing to adopt and learn.

Comment: Is this Excel or Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: You could add a column with a simple lookup that will pull your fixed targets and compare against the actual GPM values. All done with worksheet functions. If this is the type of sol'n you're looking for I can elaborate.

Comment: Yes I do believe that this is the route I'd like to persue.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a problem that require as VBA solution. Because I don't know the exact parameters of what you are doing this may or may not work. This solution won't compare the categories automatically, it will require a small amount of user input.

```
Dim MyValue1 as Variant
Dim MyValue2 as Variant
Dim MyValue3 as Variant
Dim Search as Variant
MyValue1 = InputBox("What Category do you Want to Analyze?")
'Text you enter into the input box about category must be exactly as it appears on your sheet
MyValue2 = InputBox("Enter lower %")
MyValue3 = InputBox("Enter Upper %")
For i = 1 to ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row
    If Range("A" & i) = MyValue1 Then
        If Range("E" & i) < MyValue2 Or Range("E" & i) > MyValue3 Then
            Range("A" & i & ":E" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

There are several things you need to do to get this to work. First you need to put this code into a command button on your worksheet. You can google "How to add an activeX command button to a worksheet" to learn that. Then you need to make it so your GPM% 50.42% cells just say 50.42 so the program can analyze them. If all goes well this program should highlight any cells outside your range.